#  How to fix the boot set up?

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2, wubi

I got two OSes in my PC, Ubuntu and Windows 7.

Until yesterday Windows 7 was on top of my dual-boot menu list, but I wanted to change it, so I went inside Windows configurations and put Ubuntu first, but I also set the time to `0` because I thought I could access Windows through **Grub**.

But what happens is that after I upgraded Ubuntu to 11.10, that screen with boot options don't show Windows 7 anymore.

I went online searching for a solution to my problem, most of them told me to configure some Grub options and others to use programs to do it. I've done them all and still can't access Windows 7.

Just in case my problem is not clear yet, this is how was my boot order before I messed it all up:

```
Windows 7
Ubuntu
```

with a time of `10` secs to choose between both.

This is how I wanted it to be:

```
Ubuntu
Windows 7
```

with `0` time to choose, but, inside Ubuntu I could access Windows through that Grub screen.

But this is what happens:

```
Ubuntu
Windows 7
```

`0` time, so it don't let me choose anything and jumps inside Ubuntu then inside Ubuntu `grub` doesn't show up anymore (black screen) and it starts Ubuntu normally.

I tried to fix this many times from different ways inside Ubuntu but nothing worked, also when I try do something and then upgrade my grub with `sudo upgrade-grub` it shows this message:

```
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda1
Skipping Windows 7 (loader) on Wubi system
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-12-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.0.0-12-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-12-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-12-generic
done
```

Thats why in the title I said it could probably be my WUBI messing all up.

Anyone heave a solution for this? Do you need more information?

I have a netbook so I cannot use the Windows Repair CD.

Comment: Just use `gksudo gedit` to edit your `boot.ini` in `/host`, assuming you are using Wubi.

Comment: I am using Wubi however when I use command gksudo gedit the file does not load in the text editor

Comment: You open Gedit with the command, and then open the file ith File>Open. Go into File System, `host`, and `boot.ini`.

Comment: This is a common misconception and problem among Wubi users. With XP you can fix it through the boot.ini but for Vista/Windows 7 you need a Windows repair CD (or the install DVD). Then run `bcdedit /timeout 10` from the Windows repair prompt

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, type `gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub` press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and enter your password.
You will see the following contents:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

- You can change the default from 0 to any number, corresponding to the entry in the Grub bootup menu (first entry is 0, second is 1, etc.)
- You can change the "hidden timeout" (no menu); and also display the countdown (`TIMEOUT_QUIET=false`)
- You can force the grub menu to show by commenting out the two `GRUB_HIDDEN` lines with a `#` at the beginning of the line
- And set the grub menu timeout (default is 10 seconds)
- Make your changes, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to exit.
  This will change your timneout
  To change the order of your OS menu go to the directory **/etc/grub.d**

In this directory change the prefix of the Windows7 and make it less than of the Ubuntu one
- **Important**: Open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type `sudo update-grub` to apply the changes you just made.
- Reboot and you should see your timeout/default entry change.

Comment: That will change the grub timeout, however Windows 7 does not show up in the grub menu. I need t be able to re-access the windows MBR in order to get into windows 7.

Comment: No its not true when you change the Timeout then you have time to choose the OS you want to boot from when theGrub2 menu appears

Comment: The Grub 2 menu does not have an option for windows. This is why I have been so stumped.

Comment: Does anyone need to fix my issue?

Comment: The grub menu doesn't have an option to boot Windows because it's bypassed for Wubi installs... because with Wubi you boot via the Windows boot manager (which you forced to go straight to Ubuntu), and grub only appears after that point. Even if you had the Windows entry in grub it wouldn't make any difference.